# NumberPicker с текстом

Tags: java, android

Можно ли использовать текст вместо цифр в NumberPicker ?
Если нет, есть ли аналоги NumberPicker с текстом?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно подменять значения массивом:

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(2);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" } );
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)